# TextFormField over Google Map?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is there any way to get this guy:

```
                TextFormField(
                  controller: feedbackController,
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'text input'),
```

to display on top of the below map?

```
Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: GoogleMap(
                      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                            zoom: 9.0),
                        myLocationEnabled: true,
                        compassEnabled: true,
                        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                        mapType: MapType.normal,
                        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                          controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
                        }),
                  ),
                  Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 250,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: _dosomething ,
                          child: Text("dosomething"),
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          textColor: Colors.black,)),
                    ]),
```

The raised buttons display fine thankfully... I'd like the TextFormField to be on the top or bottom of the map. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextFormField does not have a self size, it gets the size from its parent, so I suppose that's your problem. Try to Wrap the textfield in a sized box or a sized container and put into the stack:

```
Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: GoogleMap(
                      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                            zoom: 9.0),
                        myLocationEnabled: true,
                        compassEnabled: true,
                        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                        mapType: MapType.normal,
                        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                          controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
                        }),
                  ),
                  Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 250,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: _dosomething ,
                          child: Text("dosomething"),
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          textColor: Colors.black,)),
                    ]),
                  Container( 
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  child: Row(
                         children: <Widget> [

                          Expanded(
child: TextFormField(
                  controller: feedbackController,
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'text input'),
 
                        )

                          ]
                         )
                  )

    ]),
```